# Changing html label according to fetched data from db by Django

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

This is how it's supposed to look. I am trying to change HTML `class="label-warning"` or `class="label-info'` according to the status coming out of the DB.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var valueCol = $("span #label" tr td:nth-child(2)");
    if ($('#label').valueCol == 'New') {
        $('#label').addClass('label-info');
    };
    else ($('#label').valueCol == 'Rep') {
        $('#label').addClass('label-warning');
    };
    else($('#label').attr('value').val() == 'Progress') {
        $('#label').addClass('label-success');
    };
```

```html
{{account.status}}
```

So based on `.status` I want to add different classes. How can I do that?

Comment: You have some syntax problems - You have a mis-matched double quote in the selector of the jQuery object and you should remove the semicolons after your `if` and `else` conditions.

Comment: `$("span #label" tr td:nth-child(2)");` - there's a mess with quotes

Comment: I don t think this is the only problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in your Html file:

```
<script>
    var status = '{{ account.status }}';
</script>
```

and in your script file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cls = "label-info";
    if(status == Condition){
        cls = 'label-warning';
    }
    $('#label').addClass(cls);
    ...
});
```

Comment: ok, but if var cls = "label-info", would this function just add new cos, so there would be two? should i .deleteClass(label-info) an addClass('label-warning')?

Comment: Not working, and html now shows var status ='status'

Comment: First cls="label-info", but if your condition satisfied (in 'if(status == Condition)' ), then cls='label-warning' !